# Integration of Chiba with an Java Application

Tags: xforms, xforms-betterform

I am new to X-Forms & Chiba.

I was looking at integrating Chiba in a simple Java EE application.

What are the steps to do this?

What has been achieved so far

1. Submit a xform to Chiba using a stream or as a file through JSP and Servlet.
2. To get the output form from Chiba as a HTML, CSS, JS and AJAX.
3. The created xhtml x-form that will be used by Customers to fill
   in data.
4. On submit, the instance xml goes to a servlet.
5. The Servlet then saves this instance xml (assume in RDBMS as
   CLOB).

Can you provide any sample application which can help me to understand the flow of xForm processing through an server-side xform engine?

Answer (score 0):

This won't answer your core question, but if you don't already have a lot of code tied to Chiba, you will almost certainly do better to use an XForms implementation that's being actively maintained.  The main developers of Chiba are now working on betterFORM (and of course there are other Java-based implementations of XForms, if you want tight integration within Java, and non-Java-based implementations, if you want looser coupling).